# Stop Command Prompt from closing so quickly

Tags: c#, command-prompt

I'm trying to troubleshoot why the following function isn't working.

```
 public void RunCmd()
            {
                string strCmdText;
                strCmdText = "/C [enter command stuff here]";
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
            }
```

However whenever I try to run it or throw in some breakpoints, command opens, shows an error, and then closes really quickly (so quickly that I can't read anything).

Is there a way I can halt the program or figure out what's going on?  Breakpoints don't seem to be working.

When I directly type it in Command Prompt instead of running it via this c# script, it the command works fine.

Comment: Use /k instead of /c so the window won't close automatically.

Comment: how do I start `cmd` process once and pass `cmdtext` in forloop?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try this:

```
 strCmdText = "/K [enter command stuff here]";
```

/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates

/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try adding a `pause` command?

Answer (score 1):

There are a various options.  Using `/K` will prevent the window from closing.

You can also edit your command to add a [SLEEP](http://ss64.com/nt/sleep.html) after the main call.  For example, the following will wait 2 seconds before exiting:

```
public void RunCmd()
{
     string strCmdText = "/C \"[enter command stuff here]\" & \"SLEEP 2\"";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Process.Start has two parameters there: the process name and the arguments to pass to the process. CMD is having a problem understanding what the argument "[enter" is. If it is not an argument CMD understands, it will immediately exit.

Answer (score 0):

cin.get()

That waits for a keyboard press from the user.

Answer (score 0):

create temp folder under c: then append " < c:\temp\log.txt"   to the end of command. this writes the output to a file

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the tip about using /K vs /C to create a shell that 'lingers', you'll probably want to inject an empty "set" command to see what environmental variables (and paths) are set in the spawned shell.  In all likelihood, the difference between the successful run of your script in your own shell session and the one that fails in the spawned shell, is the environment settings in which it is run.