# how do i pause cmd screen after msbuild.exe execution or write output in log file?

Tags: c#, .net, cmd, msbuild

I tried following code to pause command line screen after execution of msbuild.exe

```
var solutionFile = "c:\test\myconsole.sln";
regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\3.5");
var msbuildPath = (string)regKey.GetValue("MSBuildToolsPath");;

var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{        
    Arguments = String.Format("\"{0}\" /nologo", solutionFile),
    FileName = Path.Combine(msbuildPath, "msbuild.exe")
};

var proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Any argument I can use to pause cmd screen? or write output in log file?

Comment: How about just adding a `Console.ReadLine();` at the end of your console program so the user has to press the enter key before the program exits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try launching `msbuild.exe` within and actual cmd.exe as presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023255/stop-command-prompt-from-closing-so-quickly).

**EDIT**

```
const string solutionFile = @"c:\test\myconsole.sln";
var regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\3.5");
var msbuildPath = (string) regKey.GetValue("MSBuildToolsPath");
var msBuild = Path.Combine(msbuildPath, "msbuild.exe");
var strCmdText = string.Format("/K {0} \"{1}\" /nologo", msBuild, solutionFile);

var proc = Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
// Not necessary if you don't actually want to wait for it to exit before
// proceeding to following code
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: `cmd.exe /k` will keep the window open once your command executed (your command being `msbuild.exe`).

Comment: ok can you help me to update my above code using cmd as you suggested thanks

Comment: @Neo Edited my answer

Comment: thanks I wonder how do I call this only once `var proc = Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);` and in for loop pass only `strCmdText` ? can you help?

Comment: This looks like another question. I suggest you ask a new question specifically for this.

Comment: check new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007209/how-do-i-execute-cmd-exe-process-only-once-and-in-forloop-pass-commandtext