# how do I execute cmd.exe process only once and in foreach pass commandText?

Tags: c#, winforms, cmd, msbuild

I want to execute process of `cmd.exe` only once outside `foreach` and inside foreach  want to send parameters to this process.

I am currently doing this:

```
var msbuildPath = (string) regKey.GetValue("MSBuildToolsPath");
foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
{
    var FilePath = item.ToString();         
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        Arguments = String.Format("\"{0}\" /nologo ", FilePath),
        FileName = Path.Combine(msbuildPath, "msbuild.exe")
    };

    var proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
    proc.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: foreach string in listBox, you want to add an arguement like item1/NoLogo item2/noLogo??

Comment: How do you want the arguement to look like. add some example

Comment: Sounds like you are asking about inter process communication. Very few apps support passing command line args after they are already running. To support that, the app has to implement that functionality, for example, using `NamedPipes`, or some other message passing method.

Comment: my concern is if I create new process in foreach everytime to execute `msbuild.exe` is that make application slow ? it is good ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, it should look something like this:

```
var msbuildPath = (string)regKey.GetValue("MSBuildToolsPath");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
{
   sb.AppendFormat("\"{0}\" ", item);
}
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
   WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
   Arguments = sb.ToString() + " /nologo",
   FileName = Path.Combine(msbuildPath, "msbuild.exe")
};
var proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
proc.WaitForExit();
```